# Compare two repos - a table of all all package versions?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, repository, versions

I'd like to see and compare versions of all packages in two different repos.
Something like:

libfoo | 1.2 | 1.3
libbar | 2.4 | 3.0
libbaz | ... | ...

Is there some such web?

Or a way to obtain list of all package versions in a repo, so I could compare myself by a script?

The use case is to be able to know what versions will change after system upgrade.

Comment: By definition, *all* packages will be upgraded after a release upgrade. You probably don't want to check all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tool **[rmadison](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rmadison.1.html)** for one package version information in different distributions
(well then different repositories)

1. `sudo apt-get install devscripts`
2. `rmadison [the package name]`

For example,

```
$ rmadison alsa-utils
```

and the output looks like [package version distro arch]:

```
 alsa-utils | 1.0.25-1ubuntu5   | precise         | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 alsa-utils | 1.0.25-1ubuntu5.2 | precise-updates | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 alsa-utils | 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2 | trusty          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 alsa-utils | 1.0.28-1ubuntu2   | vivid           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 alsa-utils | 1.0.29-0ubuntu1   | wily            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
```

Or you could go to this website to see the lists

**http://packages.ubuntu.com/**

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Ubuntuupdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org) as follows:

**Search according to [packages](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas):**

[image]

---

**Then click Package Search** (you will find differnt versions in page such as shown below):

[image]

---

You can also find possible matches of package name according to version and then click anyone to know more details!

[image]

---

Here package names are only used as example. Hope this helps to find appropriate **package-name + PPA according to Ubuntu-release.**

Answer (score 0):

For two different repositories, you can compare the `Packages` files. This file is specific to the release channel (`trusty`, `trusty-updates`, etc.), the component (`main`, `multiverse`, etc.) and the type of the packages (`binary-amd64`, `source`, etc.).

Typically you can locate the file at:

```
/ubuntu/dists/$CHANNEL/$COMPONENT/binary-$ARCH/Packages{,.gz,.bz2,.xz}
```

relative to the root of most official mirrors.

An example would be http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

You can fetch the `Packages` files you're interested in (uncompress if necessary), `grep` for `Package` and `Version`, then diff the output.

A sample code:

```
curl -s http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | gunzip | grep -E '^(Package|Version)' | awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS {print $2}' > repo-a.txt 
curl -s ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/distributions/ubuntu/archives/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | gunzip | grep -E '^(Package|Version)' | awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS {print $2}' > repo-b.txt 
diff repo-a.txt repo-b.txt
```